# Adding a line under another in vi

Tags: regex, vi

I am researching a regular expression that will add the following line underneath each line.

```
rewrite ^ /sniffer/loath/ permanent;
```

Answer (score 3):

More simple solution:
`%s+$+\rrewrite ^ /sniffer/loath/ permanent;+`

`$` matches the end of the existing line. So this script replaces it with a newline and exactly your text. Also, it uses `+` instead of regular `/` symbol in `s` command to avoid escaping `/` in the replacement string.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question right you want to insert a line under each existing line. To do that simply

```
:%s/\(.*\)/\1\rrewrite ^ \/sniffer\/loath\/ permanent;/
```

The `\(.*\)` matches every entire line. Then we replace that line with

- `\1` (itself)
- `\r` (a newline)
- then the text you wanted with the `/` characters escaped

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: :%s/\(.*\)/\1\rrewrite ^ \/sniffer\/loath\/ permanent;/g serves part of my purpose. What I am also looking to do is place rewrite ^ /sniffer/loath/ permanent; with a bit of space and followed by a } at the start of the next line